# cannot convert bson type string to date

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to execute this mongodb query :

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
     {$project: {yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } }}}, 

    {$match: { yearMonthDay: { $eq: "2018-03-02" } }}
 ]).count()
```

but I got this error :

```
cannot convert bson type string to date
```

Comment: It's most likely the `date` field is not a Date type. You can run this to confirm: `db.<collectionName>.aggregate([ { "$project": { "fieldType": {  "$type": "$date"  } } }  ])`

Comment: Thanks for answer but I got as result : fieldType:date